# Setting 'testFrameworks' in build.sbt of a scalajs project causes java.lang.NullPointerException when running test

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, scala.js

I am new to *scala* and *scalajs*. I am trying to add unit tests to my *scalajs* project using [minitest](https://github.com/monix/minitest). I followed instructions at https://github.com/monix/minitest#usage-in-sbt, so this is what my **build.sbt** looks like:

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, WorkbenchPlugin)
name := "Test"
version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.1",
  "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.6.1",
  "io.monix" %%% "minitest" % "2.0.0" % "test"
)
testFrameworks += new TestFramework("minitest.runner.Framework")
```

I also have a **project/build.sbt** that looks like:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.17")
addSbtPlugin("com.lihaoyi" % "workbench" % "0.3.0")
```

When I run:

```
> sbt test
```

I see this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapperLike$$anon$2.<init>(Wrappers.scala:265)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapperLike$class.iterator(Wrappers.scala:264)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapper.iterator(Wrappers.scala:275)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toMap(TraversableOnce.scala:279)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.scalajs.core.tools.json.Impl$.toMap(Impl.scala:26)
at org.scalajs.core.tools.json.JSONObjExtractor.<init>(JSONObjExtractor.scala:6)
at org.scalajs.testadapter.FrameworkInfo$Deserializer$.deserialize(FrameworkInfo.scala:24)
at org.scalajs.testadapter.FrameworkInfo$Deserializer$.deserialize(FrameworkInfo.scala:22)
at org.scalajs.core.tools.json.package$.fromJSON(package.scala:19)
at org.scalajs.testadapter.ScalaJSFramework.fetchFrameworkInfo(ScalaJSFramework.scala:66)
at org.scalajs.testadapter.ScalaJSFramework.<init>(ScalaJSFramework.scala:37)
at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$76$$anonfun$apply$52.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:873)
at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$76$$anonfun$apply$52.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:872)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$76.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:872)
at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$76.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:849)
...
```

I don't see the crash if I remove this line from **build.sbt**, but then of course my tests don't get run:

```
testFrameworks += new TestFramework("minitest.runner.Framework")
```

The problem doesn't seem specific to *minitest* because I see it with [otest](https://github.com/cgta/otest) as well. I'm not sure what I should try next to resolve this problem, so I'd appreciate any help with it.

Comment: I could reproduce this with minitest, but not with utest. I suspect that this is a bug in both minitest and otest.

Comment: What is printed if you type `show test:fullClasspath` in sbt?

Comment: I think your version of sbt-scalajs is too old for those testing frameworks. Try upgrading to 0.6.21. If that works, I'll post a full answer.